# La Ñ en arrays de php¿es posible asignar un valor del array a la Ñ?

Tags: php, array

Sigo con problemas para asignar como valor de un array a la Ñ.Cuando paso un string a array, parece que no tiene espacio. Ahora en vez de un ? no me muestra todos los carateres.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"); 
$pal="niño";
$pal=mb_strtoupper($pal);
$long=mb_strlen($pal);
echo"$long";
for($i=0;$i<$long;$i++){

        $arr[$i]=$pal[$i];

}

foreach($arr as $valor){
    echo"$valor";
}?>
```

El resultado es 4NIÑ
Me gustaria saber si los arrays de php 5.6.30 son compatibles con la Ñ.
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás experimentando es que la longitud multibyte de "niño" son 4 caracteres, pero en realidad necesitas 2 caracteres ASCII para describir un carácter especial (dado que la colección ASCII tiene menos símbolos disponibles).

En otras palabras, si tú quieres tratar la palabra como un array, determinas su largo multibyte y lo recorres, te quedas corto por un caracter o más:

Supongamos que la Ñ en ascii se escribe con la secuencia Ñ¹ y Ñ². Lo que internamente tiene la palabra que tú visualizas como "NIÑO" es

```
[
    'N',
    'I',
    'Ñ¹',
    'Ñ²',
    'O'

]
```

Solución corta: usa `strlen` en vez de `mb_strlen` para iterar 5 veces.

Solución correcta: en vez de recorrer la palabra como un array (**un byte a la vez**) recórrela como texto usando **un carácter multibyte a la vez**

```
for($i=0; $i< $long; $i++){
   $arr[$i]= mb_substr($pal,$i,1);
}

foreach($arr as $valor){
    echo "$valor";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @amenadiel , justo lo que necesitaba, esa es la manera correcta de hacerlo. Un Saludo